# 'X' object has no attribute 'functionName' - Pyspark / Python

Tags: python, pyspark

I'm new to Pyspark so just learning as I go.

I'm trying to experiment with UnitTest and I am getting some error below:

```
def drop_duplicates(df):
    df = df.dropDuplicates(df)
    return df
```

```
import unittest

class TestNotebook(unittest.TestCase):
    
    def test_drop_duplicates(self):
        data = (
            ['1', '2020-01-01 00:00:00', '2020-01-01 01:00:00', '2', '1'],
            ['1', '2020-01-01 00:00:00', '2020-01-01 01:00:00', '3', '1'],
            ['1', '2020-01-01 00:00:00', '2020-01-01 01:00:00', '2', '2'],
            ['2', '2020-01-01 00:00:00', '2020-01-01 01:00:00', '2', '1']
        )
        
        columns = ["ID", "TimeFrom", "TimeTo", "Serial", "Code"]
        df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)
        expected_data = [
            ('1', '2020-01-01 00:00:00', '2020-01-01 01:00:00', '2', '1'),
            ('1', '2020-01-01 00:00:00', '2020-01-01 01:00:00', '2', '2')
        ]
    
        
        self.assertEqual(drop_duplicates(df), expected_data)
        
res = unittest.main(argv=[''], verbosity=2, exit=False)
```

(The Assert might fail but I'll know when I move past this error) but for now I just get the following error:

```
  File "/tmp/ipykernel_15937/2907449366.py", line 2, in drop_duplicates
    df = df.dropDuplicates(df)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 4207, in dropDuplicates
    raise PySparkTypeError(
pyspark.errors.exceptions.base.PySparkTypeError: [NOT_LIST_OR_TUPLE] Argument `subset` should be a list or tuple, got DataFrame.
```

Is there something I am missing? I'm reading the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.dropDuplicates.html) on this method but can't seem to figure out.

Comment: why are you passing `df` to `df.dropDuplicates`? Don't do that. As an aside, it seems kind of pointless to create this function... why create a function `drop_duplicates(df)` that just does `df.dropDuplicates()`?

Comment: "Ignore that it will pass or fail" don' provide code that you tell us to ignore. You should *create a [mcve]* for your question.

Comment: I know what you mean. I'm trying to experiment with UnitTests and if I get it to work atleast, then i can correct the Assert as i go.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.dropDuplicates.html) for Pyspark suggests that `df.dropDuplicates` is a function which isn't supposed to take `df` as an argument. You should instead use `df.dropDuplicates()` without any arguments.